# OSError: No Default Input Device Available in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed a Django APP into AWS EC2 and used pyaudio and speech_recognition.
When I run the endpoint, it says:

> device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
> OSError: No Default Input Device Available

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  r.adjust_for_adbient_noise(source)
```

Comment: What exactly do you except your microphone to be? A physical microphone in AWS datacenter?

Comment: what I want is to recording audio from my microphone and then export real-time audio into the microphone connected in PC and iPhone like a call in skype. @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an impossible ask.

You’re running an EC2 instance, which is a **virtual machine** running on a computer of 100s & 1000s possibly etc. of *other* virtual machines.

AWS does not give you access to the microphone of the machine, as:

1. It probably doesn’t have one
2. If it did, they’d be no point as you’ll just hear data centre background noise if any
3. It 99.99% definitely won’t have one

If you need microphone input, use your local machine & not a machine in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Ermiya but have you ever hear the aws transcribe? I know it allow AWS access to pc microphone

Comment: Yes but that’s you sending your voice data - not your voice being recorded from where you are by an EC2 instance; just use AWS Transcribe if that’s what you need?

Comment: If I use the AWS Transcribe SDK in python, do you know how to recording an audio from microphone using Transcribe?

Comment: @MaSao93 Read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/transcribe-streaming-sdk-for-python-preview/ (but out of scope for this current question)

Comment: I already followed the blog and wrote it but its from an audio file, not from microphone.
What i want is to recording the audio from micro and transcribe the audio stream into the .wav file

Comment: Please open another question -  your original question has been solved

Comment: No, it never solved, I did not find the solution about my question

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to access the microphone on an EC2 instance - the answer is that is not possible.

Comment: You mean is it impossible to recording an audio from microphone in an Django app running on EC2?

Comment: You look like you want to record audio from the EC2's microphone - you should be able to record audio using Javascript client-side code and then pass that to the Django app